# Passing strings instead of variables to child Livewire components in blade files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am new to Livewire, and I understand how we can easily pass variables to livewire components in blade files. The below code does just that.

```
@php
    $CAR_MAKE = "carMake";
    $main_classes = "text-sm md:text-lg border-2";
    $placeholder = "Search";
@endphp    
<div class="flex mb-4 md:mb-9">
    <livewire:components.select :classes="$main_classes" :name="$CAR_MAKE" :placeholder="$placeholder" />  
</div>
```

But it requires creating variables first within PHP tags, and then I can pass the variables to the "select" livewire component. But it is hardcoded data, and I want to pass the data directly without creating variables. That will help in removing lots of extra PHP tags and will improve code quality. So is there a way to do that? Or if there is anything I can do to improve this?

I am hoping to get something like below(no variables declaration):

```
<div class="flex mb-4 md:mb-9">
    <livewire:components.select :classes="text-sm md:text-lg border-2" :name="carMake" :placeholder="Search" />  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing data to a component, there is one tiny difference that will determine if the content being passed should be parsed as PHP or if it should be passed as-is.

By removing the colon `:` in front, the content being passed will no longer be parsed as PHP.

```php
<livewire:components.select classes="text-sm md:text-lg border-2" name="carMake" placeholder="Search" />
```

This also means that you can pass in a string into PHP, by putting single quotes around the string you have above. This doesn't quite make sense here, as you don't need it to be treated as PHP at all in this particular case, but it demonstrates how you can use a PHP expression inside the parameter being passed.

These two approaches can be mixed in a single component, like I'm showing here - the placeholder uses the null-coalescing operator to send in a variable, but if that variable is `null`, it will default to "Search", while the other parameters are just normal strings. Note the single quotes around `'Search'` to make it a string.

```php
<livewire:components.select classes="text-sm md:text-lg border-2" name="carMake" :placeholder="$searchPlaceholder ?? 'Search'" />
```